# Convert SortedMap Data Type

Tags: scala, collections, sortedmap

I have a nested map Data Structure of the following type:

```
SortedMap[Time: Long,SortedMap[Name: String, Value: Double]]
```

"Time" elements are of type `Long` and indicate the timestamp of the data.
"Name" elements are of type `String` and indicate the name of the element.
"Value" elements are of type `Double` and indicate the elements value for timestamp "Time".

The basic idea is that for each timestamp, we have several elements, each has a specific value for the current timestamp.

The result i want is an `Array[Double]` or `List[Double]` for each "Name" element. I don't need the "Time" value except i want the result to be ordered in the same way.

Example:

```
val dataType = SortedMap(1000L -> SortedMap("component1" -> 1.0, 
  "component2" -> 1.1), 2000L -> SortedMap("component1" -> 1.1), 
   3000L -> SortedMap("component1" -> 0.95))
```

The result i want is the following:

```
"component1" - 1.0, 1.1, 0.95
"component2" - 1.1
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Could you explain your question more clearly? What data `SortedMap` stores? What is `Time`?

Comment: Can you give a short scala snippet, question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the result-type you want is a `Map[String, Seq[Double]`. I will use a `Vector` for the sorted values, because it has an efficient append method `:+`.

First, you want to drop the time-keys of the outer map. You can use `values` or `valuesIterator` for that. Then perhaps the easiest is to perform a "fold-left" over these values, starting with an empty result map and updating it at each step. You need two nested folds, because you iterate first over the maps and then over the individual elements of each map.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap
val dataType = SortedMap(
  1000L -> SortedMap("component1" -> 1.0, "component2" -> 1.1),
  2000L -> SortedMap("component1" -> 1.1), 
  3000L -> SortedMap("component1" -> 0.95)
)

(Map.empty[String, Vector[Double]] /: dataType.values) { case (res0, map) =>
  (res0 /: map) { case (res1, (key, value)) =>
    res1.updated(key, res1.getOrElse(key, Vector.empty) :+ value)
  }
}

// Map(component1 -> Vector(1.0, 1.1, 0.95), component2 -> Vector(1.1))
```

Note the fold-left call `(init /: coll) …`. You can use the alternative method `coll.foldLeft(init) …` which yields slightly different syntax:

```
dataType.values.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Vector[Double]]) { case (res0, map) …
```

You can swap `Map` for `SortedMap` in the result if you want the component names to remain sorted.